# iOS addChildViewController on viewWillAppear

Tags: ios

I have A viewController and B viewController, on A `viewWillAppear` add B to A use `addChildViewController`. On B just go through `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` not go into `viewWillAppear`, when I add B to A on `viewDidAppear`, the life cycle will all go through.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear - 
Regarding the View Life Cycle - ViewDidload will fire up once when you do the initial load - it will do viewwillappear and viewdidappear many times  when you move from 1 app to another and go back to the app, when you move from 1 tab to another  when you have a navigation bar that goes to another view controller and then you return.  If you add a view controller on a view willAppear - it will try to add a view controller whether or not you have one existing every time the mother view controller appears.

So - usually you put the add view controllers on another function (usually an ()IBAction) using a button) - you can put it in viewdidload if you want so it will load once - or if there is a good reason why you need it in view will appear - use a switch so if it is already loaded you do not create a new instance.

Comment: Hi, Paulo. Thank you for your answer.This happen to my detail page, I have three custom button tab every tab has an view from other viewcontroller, and first page will auto do addchildviewcontroller  after my service request get the response on the viewwillappear, and I'm set the view and data on the child vc's viewwillapprear. When the request is slow there is np, but request is fast and get response before the viewdidappear the child vc's viewwillappear will not go through so my first page is empty

Comment: In other words you get to display the main view but not the child view.  ...  you probably have this kind of code:

Comment: There is a command to refresh the view - [self.view setNeedsDisplay]  you will need to call that (in the main viewcontroller)  after you fix the childviewcontroller ...   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];  if you still have problems display your code.  Note, you typically try to minimise any code in viewwillAppear and ViewdidAppear because the get called multiple times, I sty ill do not understand the reason why you have code there.